# number of integral solutions of the equation

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Find the number of integral solutions of $\large 2x + y + z = 20$ with $x, y, z \ge 0$ ?

I saw a method of generating function but i donot have knowledge about generating function  any alternative way to solve this  , answer = 121

Answer (score 3):

$y+z=20-2x$ is one of $20,18,16,\cdots0$, so that there are $$21+19+17+\cdots1=121$$ solutions.

Comment: very compact form sir please explain a bit

Comment: @sumitgoyal: what don't you understand ?

Comment: no i dont got you  y+z is one of  ??  you didnot took x in consideration ? sir

Comment: @sumitgoyal: I just used $y+z=20-2x$ and assigned $x$ all the values it can take.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017905/find-the-number-of-integral-solutions-of-2x-y-z-20?rq=1  i found same question here , can you explain  how to  use star and bars sir

Comment: got it thanku.,,,